# Посчитать стоимость вызова Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Есть следующий датафрейм с минутами разговора:

```
Time
5:21
0:21
10:31
```

Необходимо посчитать стоимость звонка исходя из следующей логики: 1 минута - 1 рубль, 2-10 минуты - 0,5 р. , с 11- минуты - 0,3р

Соответственно , как получить на выходе стоимость?

```
Time    Cost
5:21    2,5
0:21    1
10:31   5,8
```

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая для одного времени считает цену и потом `apply` ещё на всю колонку сделайте. А сама функция - ну, логику надо просто тщательно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дам в виде алгоритма, т.к. в вопросе не приведены собственные попытки решения.

1. создайте три дополнительных столбца с количеством минут для каждой из категорий тарификации
2. умножьте каждый из этих столбцов на соответствующий тариф и просуммируйте